# Delphi 2009 TurboPower library conversions

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, turbopower

In the next few months I will be resurrecting a project which made extensive use of Orpheus and SysTools. The development system I used is long gone, so would like to update the libraries to my current development environment.

My question(s): is anyone porting, or has anyone ported the TurboPower libraries to Tiburon, if so did you encounter any problems; and if the answer is nobody, is it worth collaborating to produce a Delphi 2009 version, sharing the load.

Answer (score 5):

Some components in the process of being ported to Delphi 2009, including 5 TurboPower libraries.  No Orpheus or SysTools, though.

http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/

Update:

As M Plaut pointed out, Orpheus has been added to the site and has been updated as recently as Nov 13.

Answer (score 1):

Orpheus407AU_3 was posted at http://sourceforge.net/projects/tporpheus/ on Sept 5, 2009.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Orpheus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tporpheus/) project at SourceForge but last release was made in 2005 :(
[Systools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/) is also to be found there.

Comment: Yes, I have those links, and the news.turbocontrol.com NNTP groups, but since they were dead I thought I'd ask in this new and vibrant community :)

Answer (score 0):

When turbo power closed their doors, I analysed my code that was using Orpheus and SysTools. I found that there were only a handful of SysToosl functions I was using and so we wrote our own functions. (Can't remember what they were)

It was fairly straight forward, some of them were in the newer versions of Delphi and the rest were easy to code.

Orpheus was a little more difficult. I would be willing to throw some time into bringing back Orpheus. We replaced it with standard Delphi components and some code, but our applications lacks some of the coolness it once had.

Answer (score 0):

We would definitely be looking to port this as well.  We use alot of Orpheus components in our current applications and this would be a definite roadblock to Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 0):

As of 10-11-2008, there is a version at http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/

of Orpheus as well. The following comments are attached:

*This is based on the version from CVS. The first two packages compile and are partly tested. Some asm code still needs updating. Some bugfixing also need to be found and fixed. Contributions are welcome (use the contact form on the top). Search for "FIXME" in the source.
Files that may need special attention and bugfixes: OVCDRPVW.PAS, OVCPF.PAS, OVCEDITU.PAS, OVCVIEWR.PAS, OVCSTR.PAS*

Answer (score 0):

I have to bring a very old project to delphi 2009 : a CNC editor. The project didn't use Orheus at that time, but I was looking into it (did some tests), and the orpheus text editor is still the fastest on the market. So yes, I am very interested. I tried to compile the old source in delphi 9, but it crashes. 
I am not a good programmer, but I can do tests for you.